# webpack-dev-server 'Cannot GET /'

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server

I have the following webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    // publicPath: __dirname + '/dist/',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "/dist",
    hot: true,
  } 
}
```

My understanding is that `contentBase` tells the webpack dev server where to serve files from.  So if I go to `localhost:8080/test.txt`, under this configuration the file at `myProjectRoot/dist/test/txt` will be sent by the server to the browser.  Is that correct? What does `output.publicPath` have to do with all that?

Now I have `index.html` and `bundle.js` sitting in `myProjectRoot/dist/` right now.  (although I think `bundle.js` is a bit of a confusing factor because its actually the in memory bundle that is returned by webpack-dev-server but nonetheless).  Given my previous paragraph, I'd expect the server to return `index.html` to the browser.  Since the `contentBase` is `/dist` and `index.html`'s path on disk is `./dist/index.html`.

But instead I see: `Cannot GET /`

So again, if I go to `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js` I see the full javascript bundle (up to date with what was last saved in my text editor).  But then `/index.html` wins up with `Cannot GET /`?

What am I missing?

Comment: Alex, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you can try to add static to the `devServer`?

I got this information from: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchfiles

I've put the file in the same folder, so I use `./` for my path.

This is how I did it:

```
devServer: {
   //....//
   static: {                               
     directory: path.join(__dirname, './'),  
     watch: true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alex. You wrote that:

> My understanding is that contentBase tells the webpack dev server where to serve files from

this is not exactly right. **contentBase** option is used to tell server where to serve only **static** files. But the problem is that when you are working with webpack-dev-server it generates dynamic output (bundle) in memory, so you don't have the static content to serve.

1) You should remove contentBase option as by default webpack-dev-server uses **output.path** value as the path to serve files from.

2) Then, right now you don't have index.html in your ./dist folder. If you want your index.html file to be generated and served by dev server you should use **html-webpack-plugin** that generates index.html file with all bundled files included as links in it. If you need more than default markup that this plugin generates you should look at its template option

so your webpack cofig might look like:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    // module: { rules: [ ... ] }
    devServer: {
        index: index.html
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html"
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: This almost fixed the issue for me. Not sure if webpack has updated since this post but I used this instead:

devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, './')
        }
    }

Comment: Results in error `[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: index is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

You need to set relative or absolute path in `devServer.contentBase`.
`webpack-dev-server` do not use your project as root directory, so it does not resolve `/dist` to folder within your project directory.

Try this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname + '/dist'
    // contentBase: 'dist'
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me. Even if I use publicPath instead of contentBase.

Answer (score 1):

I put index.html in the /public folder and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solutions for about two hours and couldn't fix the problem. My solution is to use your text editor's live server plugin. For example, I use Atom and the plugin is atom-live-server. VS Code has also a plugin.