# "Cannot GET / " webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack, rxjs

In order to prevent this question being marked as duplicate, I want to mention that I have referred to a number of similar SO questions and tried the accepted/most upvoted answers, but those did not help:

1. [webpack-dev-server 'Cannot GET /'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260851/webpack-dev-server-cannot-get)
2. [Cannot GET / - localhost 8080 not working with webpack dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054930/cannot-get-localhost-8080-not-working-with-webpack-dev-server)
3. [Cannot GET / error running hello world in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954809/cannot-get-error-running-hello-world-in-webpack)
4. [Plugin not defined in webpack configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604421/plugin-not-defined-in-webpack-configuration-file)

I am trying to create a simple Javascript application which uses RxJs, by following the tutorial at https://www.javatpoint.com/rxjs-first-example.

When I start webpack-dev-server, I get "Cannot GET /" error.

I have committed the code here to a git repository for it to be reproduced easily. Here are the steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/phalgunv/basic-rxjs-starter.git
npm run start
```

Open "http://localhost:8080/", I get the error
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @dave-kiss for pointing in the right direction, the key idea being the use of  [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) and [HtmlLoader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/).

I have committed the changes to the repository https://github.com/phalgunv/basic-rxjs-starter.git in the branch bug-fix-content-not-served for reference.

Here are the steps followed:

1. Install html-load

   npm install --save-dev html-loader html-webpack-plugin
2. Update webpack.config.js modules->rules with html-loader

   module: {
   rules: [
   {
   test: /.tsx?$/,
   use: "ts-loader",
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   },
   {
   test: /.html$/,
   loader: "html-loader",
   },
   ],
   },
3. Update webpack.config.js with HtmlWebpackPlugin

   plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   template: "src/index.html",
   }),
   ],
4. Remove `<script>` tag from index.html

Check the commit - https://github.com/phalgunv/basic-rxjs-starter/commit/15d0779614ccd0428bb47bc308bea8f7f0509ea0 for refernce.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is correct; based on your filename settings in Webpack, your bundle is located at `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js`

If you'd like to copy over an `index.html` file to serve the contents of your bundle, you may want to take a look at `HtmlWebpackPlugin` here: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/

Comment: When I visit locslhost:8080, I want the index.html to be rendered by the browser. And as a consequence, the RxJs code in index.ts to be executed.